# oracle uppcase column zend framework 2 authentication

Tags: php, oracle, authentication, zend-framework2, oci8

I have a simple crud system with zf2 and oracle.

But oracle has a issue with column name: They always came uppercase.

I was able to manager adding this code in entities :

```
public function exchangeArray(array $data)
  {
    $dataInner = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
      $dataInner[strtolower($key)] = $value;
    }
    ...
```

So far so good! All system is running perfectly.

But problem now is login.

After a valid login I retrieve user from database

```
public function authenticate(){
$zendDb = $this->sm->get('\Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');

$adapter = new DbTable($zendDb);

$adapter->setIdentityColumn('identity')
  ->setTableName('user')
  ->setCredentialColumn('credencial')
  ->setIdentity($this->identity)
  ->setCredential($this->credential);

$authentication  = new AuthenticationService();
$authentication->setAdapter($adapter);
$result = $authentication->authenticate();

if ($result->isValid()) {
  $usuario = $authentication->getAdapter()->getResultRowObject(null, "CREDENCIAL");
  /*
    $usuario == object(stdClass)#285 (3) { 
        ["ID"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["IDENTITY"]=> string(5) "bruno" 
        ["CREDENTIAL"]=> string(5) "admin" 
      }
  */
  $authentication->getStorage()->write($usuario);
  return true;
} else {
  $this->messages = $result->getMessages();
  return  false;
}

}
```

Controller:

```
$authentication = new AuthenticationService();
$this->layout()->setVariable('user', $authentication->getIdentity());
return array('user'=>$authentication->getIdentity());
```

View

```
echo  $this->user->IDENTITY;
```

---

What can I do to use

```
echo  $this->user->identity;
```

instead

```
echo  $this->user->IDENTITY;
```

Comment: how you get data from oracle, write your code if you want help...

Comment: the information comes from here 
`$authentication->getAdapter()->getResultRowObject(null, "credencial");` 
but if you want to see complete method I did an update

Answer (score 0):

try use upper case name of field

```
...
$adapter
  ->setTableName('user')
  ->setIdentityColumn('IDENTITY')
  ->setCredentialColumn('CREDENCIAL')
...
```